# Determining when cell in DataGridView has changed, But only after exiting Edit Mode

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

I have read several posts on this topic but none of them seem to fit my exact situation. I basically want to execute some code to copy data from a DataGridView cell once the user has made any changes. But specifically, I only want to grab the value after the user has finished editing the cell AND if the cell value actually is different (e.g. the user didn't cancel the edit). The behavior I am looking for is identical to how Excel updates formulas for cells only after the user has actually updated the formula for the cell. So far, Here is the code I am starting with:

```
private void MyDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Exit this event procedure if no rows have been added to the DataGridView yet (during program initialization)
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Get an object reference to the current Value cell
    DataGridViewCell cell = (DataGridViewCell)MyDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];

    // Do other stuff with the cell data here   
}

private void MyDataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Force the CellValueChanged event to trigger for the control if the current cell's value has changed
    if (MyDataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        MyDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

It works in that the CellValueChanged event fires every time an edit is made. However, the event fires each time the user types in a key while in edit mode, and I just want to have it fire once after the user exits edit mode (and assuming that changes were made and were not canceled). What is the best way to approach this? I've also looked at the `CellEndEdit` event, which seems to get me a bit closer, but I still don't have a way to determine if the edit was committed or canceled. Whats the best/recommended approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

OK everyone, I found a simple solution to my problem. To get this to work, all you need to do is use the CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit events. I created a global variable called CellValue, which is set to the contents of the cell inside the CellBeginEdit event. Later, this stored value is checked against the cell's current value in the CellEndEdit event. If they are different, then I can execute the code I need to handle the newly changed data in the cell.

I know this approach may not work for every situation, but just thought I would share for anyone else running into the same problem. Here's a quick code sample illustrating what I did:

```
// Temporarily holds the value of a cell in the DataGridView once a cell has begun to be edited.
// The value in this variable is then compared to the value of the cell after the edit is complete to see if the data chagned before updating the controlParameters object
object CellValue;

private void MyDataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Set this variable to the current cell's value to compare later to see if it's contents have changed
    this.CellValue = MyDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
}

private void MyDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Exit this event procedure if no rows have been added to the DataGridView yet (during program initialization)
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Proceed only if the value in the current cell has been changed since it went into edit mode
    if (this.CellValue != MyDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value)
    {
        // Do your cell data manipulation here
    }
}
```